Convert all img tags into amp-img in wordpress content area
i have this code for our custom amp page in wordpress this code remove our all images in content area but i want these images show as a amp images
$content = get_the_content();
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content);          
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);

$content = str_replace("https://www.youtube.com/embed/","",$content);

$content = preg_replace('/<iframe\s+.*?\s+src=(".*?").*?<\/iframe>/', '<amp-youtube
    data-videoid=$1
    layout="responsive"
    width="480" height="270"></amp-youtube>', $content);                
echo $content;

help me out how to customize preg_replace function to replace  tags to <amp images

Much like you've done with the iframes, you would need a more specific regular expression to pull out (at least) the src and alt from the img tag, then build your <amp-img> tag using those. Also, the $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content); will do literally nothing; you're replacing ]]> with ]]> for no reason I can discern.

thanks for help can you give me code line how to do that. second for iframe is for youtube tags
